# Need help formatting string literal regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need help creating a regex, I have a string called `filter`. I need to use the jQuery function `.replaceAll()` to search for any instance of `{0}` and replace it with the `value` variable.

What I tried:

```
filter = filter.replaceAll('/^{0}$/', value);
filter = filter.replaceAll('/{0}/', value);
filter = filter.replaceAll('^{0}$', value);
```

Comment: jQuery `.replaceAll()` is for DOM manipulation see http://api.jquery.com/replaceall/. Someone posted the right answer using regex and `replace` which is a string manipulation method that can replace multiple instances when used with regex `g` flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape `{` and `}` that have special meaning in regex pattern.

Try `\{0\}`

Remove `^` and `$` to replace all matches any where in the string.

- `^` - assert position at start of the string
- `$` - assert position at end of the string

Here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/wO8eU8/2)

sample code: (use `g` modifier to match all)

```
var re = /\{0\}/g;
var str = 'a {0} b {0} c';
var subst = '';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Comment: @ism: You have your regex literal syntax surrounded by single quotes.

Comment: remove the string around the regex, regex expression like that do not need quotes